# How to install my android application on my friend's mobile without using eclipse

Tags: android

I have developed an application in Android 2.3.3. I want to install it in my friend's android mobile and test it.

one way is to take my computer and plug his device and run the application and it will be installed automatically.

If i send him the .apk file, and if he launches the .apk file, will it start to work automatically or is there any procedure to follow.

I search quite few sites regarding this, but couldn't find much help...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send him the apk and this is the command to install and it will start working automatically:

in windows

```
adb install path_to_your_app.apk
```

in linux/ubuntu

```
./adb install path_to_your_app.apk
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to send him the .apk file (even as an email attachment or, my personal favorite, a Google Drive file), but you have to enable installation of non-market apps in Settings > Security.

Answer (score 1):

Compile it by letting it run once in Eclipse's emulator.

Then, navigate to your project folder and you can find the apk inside the bin folder. You can send that apk to anyone. It'll prompt the install on launch as long as he checked the untrusted sources application box in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Send your apk file to your friend in mail or send it via bluetooth then follow below step.

- Copy the APK file to your Android’s sdcard in your phone.
- Download and install the Apps Installer application from the Android
  Market
- Once installed, the Apps Installer will display the APK files on the
  memory card.
- Click and install your APK files.

**Note:** You can find your apk file in project's bin folder. but before this you have to enable unknow Source . Got to Settings -> Applications -> and Enable Unknown Sources.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, mail apk to your friend's google account and download from the mail, and install it as ExistentialEnso suggested